# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visualization' in jupyter notebook python

Tags: python, tensorflow, module, jupyter-notebook, visualization

I follow the notes and practice Neural Networks on jupyter notebook python,
At first I'm having problem with `import tensorflow as tf`
and then I look up on youtube and created new environment called **tf** in Anaconda Navigator and install tensorflow and keras.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNa5n.png)

Next note that I follow is
`**from visualization import draw_nn_graph**`
when i use this code, it shows `**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named` visualization`**`

i open command prompt and type `**pip install visualization**` in Command Prompt and it says succesfully installed, but it **still cannot run**. I need help

Comment: How did you install Jupyter ? From Anaconda ? If yes, are you runnning pip install in the anaconda prompt or in a System prompt ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You almost certainly have 2 Python installations, Doing `pip install` is installing the module in the installation you don't expect. You can find out where `pip` installs stuff by doing `pip --version`: after `from` it will show the location of the Python installation it targets.

Comment: @thebuleon29 
 i install jupyter in Anaconda;
this is the note and i follow exactly whats in the note;
first im having trouble in code : import tensorflow as tf;
and i look up some youtube and create new environment and install tensorflow and keras;
i did this on anaconda.navigator;
next i follow exactly the note say: from visualization import draw_nn_graph;
then there is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visualization';
i look up and i already try 'pip install visualization' in command prompt;
it still having an error

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned the command prompt in the comments, I assume that you are on Windows. What is happening here is that you have two separate Python installations: one "normal", directly installed on Windows, and the Anaconda one. When you ran the `pip install` command in the prompt, you installed the module for the normal version, but since Jupyter is using the Anaconda install it cannot find it.

[image: Anaconda Prompt]

This image shows you an example of this. The right window is my command prompt, and it does not know Python since I did not install it. However, I have Anaconda installed, and with it comes a tool called Anaconda Prompt. You can see it on the left, that one knows Python. You should have this Anaconda prompt as well. Search for it in the start menu, run your `pip install` there and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: hi @thebuleon29 updated.,
now i managed to install visualization using command
`! pip install visualization` , in the Jupyter Notebook (in the anaconda environment called  tf that I created)
it successfully installed.

Now for command 
`from visualization import draw_nn_graph`
I got `FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tf\Library\bin\geos_c.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.`

Answer (score -1):

the question solved by
`!pip install visualization`; in the Jupyter Notebook in environment called tf that I created

Comment: This is not an answer to the posted question. Additional information to the question must be edited into the question itself.

Comment: ok sir, understood

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).